# Delete MySQL row where multiple indexes are the same, but keep the most recent

Tags: mysql, duplicates, relational-database, delete-row

Here is what my table looks like 
=======================================
|| id | collection_id | product_id | price ||
=======================================
|| 1  |   1    |   1   | 2.50  ||
|| 2  |   1    |   1   | 2.60  ||
|| 3  |   1    |   1   | 2.40  ||
|| 4  |   2    |   1   | 2.50  ||
=======================================

Here is a rough outline of what I want to achieve; ***using some pseudo code.***

What I want to do is **DELETE FROM** prices **WHERE** *(collection*_ *id && product*_ *id are duplicated)* **AND WHERE** *(id < highest duplicated row)*

SO what I want to do in plain English is delete rows where the id is equal to 1 & 2 but keep the row where the id is equal to 3 because this the newest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple `DELETE JOIN` should do it; delete all rows where there exists at least one row with a matching `collection_id` and `product_id` and a greater value of `id`;

```
DELETE p1
FROM prices p1
JOIN prices p2
  ON p1.collection_id = p2.collection_id
 AND p1.product_id = p2.product_id
 AND p1.id < p2.id
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/97db2/1), and remember to always back up your data before running updates or deletes from random people on the Internet.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I am not running this until I understand it. I can see it works from the fiddle but I can't see how. Where are p1 & p2 coming from? and what happens if there is fifty values?

Is this a pseudo table?

Comment: OK so I've tested this in the fiddle with 10 lines and it works, can you explain what this is doing?

Comment: @gcoulby Basically, it's a regular `JOIN`. The query picks two rows from the table `prices` and call them `p1` and `p2`. If the conditions are true (ie their rows match and p1 has a lower id), we delete p1 from the table. It then basically repeats for every row combination in the table, so the end result is that all rows that have a matching row with a greater id have been deleted.

Comment: Ahh that makes a lot of sense now. I didn't use it in this project, but this came in very handy for a second project. In this project I put in code that detected duplicates on entry and automatically deleted old ones.